# Sending json data into db and display in listview throws "null pointer exception"

Tags: java, android, database, json

I am getting json data from server and i want to pass that data to my db, i want to display those data in my listview,now its thowing some null pointer exception.

Mainactivity.java

```
   public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements FetchDataListener,OnClickListener{
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int TAG_CATEGORY = 0;
    private static final String CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT = "content";
    private static final String CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT = "count";
    private static final int Application = 0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    ListView lv;
    ListView lv1;
    private List<Application> items;
    private Button btnGetSelected;
    private Button praycount;
    public int pct;
    private String stringVal;
    private TextView value;
    private int prayers;
    private int prayerid;
    EditText myFilter;
    ApplicationAdapter adapter;
     private GinfyDbAdapter mDbHelper;
     JSONArray contacts = null;
        private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item); 
        mDbHelper=new GinfyDbAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());


        lv1 =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list); 
        lv =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);



        btnGetSelected = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnget);
        btnGetSelected.setOnClickListener(this);

        myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);


        // Adding items to listview


        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */




        new GetDataAsyncTask().execute();
        //praycount.setOnClickListener(this);
        //initView();
    }



    /*private void initView(){
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
        String url = "http://www.ginfy.com/api/v1/posts.json";
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);


    }   */

    private class GetDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("Loading.....");
            Dialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Dialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            getProdData();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void getProdData() {
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONParser  jsonObject = new JSONParser();
        //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            //JSONArray aJson = jsonObject.getJSONArray("post");
            String url = "http://www.ginfy.com/api/v1/posts.json";
            // getting JSON string from URL
            //JSONArray aJson = jsonObject.getJSONArray(url);
            JSONArray Json = jsonObject.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            try {
                // Getting Array of Contacts
                contacts = Json.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORY);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID);
                    String title = c.getString(CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE);
                    String  content = c.getString(CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT);
                    String  count = c.getString(CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT);

                    mDbHelper.saveCategoryRecord(new Category(id,title,content,count));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void fillData() {
        mDbHelper.open();   
        Cursor projectsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllProjects();
        //startManagingCursor(projectsCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text2, R.id.text1, R.id.count};

        /* Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter projects = 
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_row, projectsCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(projects);
        */
        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
        //as well as the layout information
         dataAdapter  = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
          this, R.layout.activity_row, 
          projectsCursor, 
          from, 
          to,
          0);
         setListAdapter(dataAdapter);




    }



    private void setListAdapter(SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

It showing error in this line  `registerForContextMenu(getListView());` it thows null pointer exception.

mycategory.java

```
public class Category {

    String _id; 
    String title; 
    String content;
    String count;
    public Category(String id, String title, String content, String count) {
        super();
        this._id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.count = count;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return _id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this._id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

this is my db part like this i am giving

```
public class GinfyDbAdapter {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ = "projects";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    public static final String CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT = "content";
    public static final String CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT = "count";


    private static final String TAG = "GinfyDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private static SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private final Context mCtx;





    public void saveCategoryRecord(String id, String title, String content, String count) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID, id);
        contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE, title);
        contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, content);
        contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT, count);
        mDb.insert(DATABASE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        }
    public Cursor getTimeRecordList() {
        return mDb.rawQuery("select * from " + DATABASE_NAME, null);
        }
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }



        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_PROJ =
                "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ + " ("
                + CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key , "
                + CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE + " text not null, " + CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT + " text not null, " + CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT + " integer );" ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String DATABASE_CREATE_PROJ = "CREATE TABLE " +  DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ + "( "
                + CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT, " + CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT + " TEXT, " + CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT + " INTEGER   );" ;
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_PROJ);     
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ DATABASE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }


}

    public void saveCategoryRecord(Category category) {

        String query = "insert into"+ DATABASE_NAME+ " values( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
        SQLiteStatement stmt = mDb.compileStatement(query);
        stmt.bindString(1, category.getId());
        stmt.bindString(2, category.getTitle());
        stmt.bindString(3, category.getContent());
        stmt.bindString(4, category.getCount());
        stmt.execute();
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllProjects() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ, new String[] {CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID, CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE, CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public GinfyDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;

    }

     public GinfyDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
            mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
            mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }


}
```

Is it my code is correct to send an json data into an database and show in an listview

Logcat error is

```
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jsonandroid/com.example.jsonandroid.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at android.app.Activity.registerForContextMenu(Activity.java:2857)
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at com.example.jsonandroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-05 08:59:57.605: E/AndroidRuntime(30062):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Comment: Where is the `logcat` data ?? Where are you getting `exception`? Please be more informative...

Comment: @AvadhaniY i added logcat part also

Comment: @KarthickM you are inserting 4 values so change that line also String query = "insert into"+ DATABASE_NAME+ " values( ?, ?, ?, ? )";

Comment: @NareshSharma ya i changed,its not working

Comment: @KarthickM check your db by pulling out from the file explorer in ddms perspective

Comment: @Raghunandan  how to check after going to the file explorer,in file exploere what to check dude

Comment: @KarthickM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007395/how-to-upload-images-in-gallery-of-android-emulator/16007494#16007494. check here there is button that can pull the file from file explorer. You need to select the db from your package and then pull the file.

Comment: after pull it what it will shows dude @Raghunandan

Comment: @KarthickM check some tutorial dude. i can'r comment on each and every step. Download some db viewer for your os and check for the data entry

Comment: @Raghunandan not getting dude

Comment: @Raghunandan actually its shwoing some list problem,its going to that page and loading sometimes after that it shows who application has stopped

Comment: @KarthickM post your question as a new thread.

Comment: i accept your answer for null pointer exception,i will make another thread for that doubt @Raghunandan

Comment: @KarthickM you are welcome and if not i, i am sure the community will help you.

Comment: @KarthickM the below works. i tried it on emulator i get the data. Modify the same.

Comment: @Raghunandan, thanks for helping me dude,first time its saving into db dude,but after update anything in website,its not update dude,not any changes

Comment: @KarthickM i am not aware of how you get the data from the website. But with what you posted this all we can do to help. it may also depend on how you retrieve data from server or website which of out of scope of this location.

Comment: @Raghunandan actually the json part is automatically updated if adding data in website,everytime if we load in our apps it will automatically shown

Comment: @KarthickM i am not aware of that part. I suggest you open a new thread by posting the relevant code. I am sure the community will help you further.

Comment: ok dude sure,thanks for your help,keep in touch with me@Raghunandan

Comment: @Raghunandan are you there

Comment: @Raghunandan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547314/my-database-is-not-updated-if-my-json-data-will-increase-also

Comment: @Raghunandan i post question also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class does not extend `ListActivity`.

```
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView()

`public ListView getListView ()`

Get the activity's list view widget.

And you have this which can be removed.

```
private View getListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null; // returning null
}
```

You also have this

```
 lv1 =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list); 
 lv =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Both refer to the same resource id.

From your comments you say you get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list
```

Your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)

```
           <ListView 
           android:id="@android:id/list" // must have this
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#00FF00"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
```

Edit:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{// implements FetchDataListener,OnClickListener{
     private GinfyDbAdapter mDbHelper;
     JSONArray contacts = null;
        private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        mDbHelper=new GinfyDbAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        Cursor projectsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllProjects();
        if(projectsCursor!=null)
        {
        fillData(projectsCursor);
        }
        else
        {
             new GetDataAsyncTask().execute();
        }
    }

    private class GetDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("Loading.....");
            Dialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Dialog.dismiss();

            Cursor projectsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllProjects();
            if(projectsCursor!=null)
            {
            mDbHelper=new GinfyDbAdapter(MainActivity.this);
            mDbHelper.open();
            fillData(projectsCursor);
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            getData();
            return null;
        }
    }
    public void getData()
    {
          try
            {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.ginfy.com/api/v1/posts.json");
        // HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/mbbangalore/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc");     

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); // content will be consume only once
         Log.i("................",_response);
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(_response);
        JSONArray contacts = jsonObject.getJSONArray("post");//(url);
            for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString("id");
                String title = c.getString("title");
                String  content = c.getString("content");
                String  count = c.getString("content");
                mDbHelper=new GinfyDbAdapter(MainActivity.this);
                mDbHelper.open();
                mDbHelper.saveCategoryRecord(new Category(id,title,content,count));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void fillData(Cursor projectsCursor) {
        //mDbHelper.open();   

        if(projectsCursor!=null)
        {
        String[] from = new String[]{GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3};
         dataAdapter  = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
          this, R.layout.activity_row, 
          projectsCursor, 
          from, 
          to,
          0);
         setListAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }else
        {
            Log.i("...........","null");
        }
    }
}
```

The other change in your DB class

```
void saveCategoryRecord(Category category) {
      ///  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE , category.getTitle());
        values.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, category.getContent()); 
        values.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT, category.getCount());   
        // Inserting Row
        mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ, null, values);
        mDb.close(); // Closing database connection

    }
```

Comment: ya i put into listactivity eventhough it shows error in that line

Comment: @KarthickM your doing it wrong `getListView` is a method of `ListActivity`

Comment: ya i changed activity into listactivity,what i want to change dude @Raghunandan

Comment: what does this `registerForContextMenu(getListView())` do ?

Comment: i want to remove that line ah dude @Raghunandan

Comment: @KarthickM i don't know what you are doing. what is that method used for?

Comment: actually dude i saw one example and did one dude,my need is json data shoul be store in db and it has to display in listview,....if i remove that line it shows like this 07-05 09:18:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(1300): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jsonandroid/com.example.jsonandroid.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: @KarthickM what should i do code for you. tell us what is the problem facing then if i know i will help.

Comment: dude previously i get the json data and display in listview without storing an data in db,now i want to store the db and after that i want to display in listview @Raghunandan

Comment: your nullpointerexception is solved?. Check your dbhelper class where you insert data. soemthing might wrong there.

Comment: Does data get inserted to db? You face problem displaying the data?

Comment: Dont know dude,whether its inserting into db or not,@Raghunandan any way is there to check its created db part or not

Comment: @KarthickM dude i will suggest you to first check whether data is getting inserted first and then come back and post a new question.

Comment: ,how to check whether its inserting my json data into db or not,if its running only i can check whether its inserting or not,but i am sure my json having valude,can i send my code to you dude

Comment: @KarthickM i will post the implementation here by editing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Extend your activty from ListActivity