# My Database is not updated,if my JSON data will increase also

Tags: java, android, database, json

I am parsing JSON data to database,that data shows in my lisview.But in the first time it get data from my JSON and stores in db,its not upgrading if i add anything in my website,the json also will increase but its not reflect in db,the database part also not upgrading.Just its simply the display the first fetched data only.

Ginfydbadapter.java

```
public class GinfyDbAdapter {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ = "projects";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    public static final String CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT = "content";
    public static final String CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT = "count";


    private static final String TAG = "GinfyDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private static SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private final Context mCtx;





    public void saveCategoryRecord(String id, String title, String content, String count) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID, id);
        contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE, title);
        contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, content);
        contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT, count);
        mDb.insert(DATABASE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        }
    public Cursor getTimeRecordList() {
        return mDb.rawQuery("select * from " + DATABASE_NAME, null);
        }
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }



        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_PROJ =
                "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ + " ("
                + CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key , "
                + CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE + " text not null, " + CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT + " text not null, " + CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT + " integer );" ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String DATABASE_CREATE_PROJ = "CREATE TABLE " +  DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ + "( "
                + CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key, "
                + CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE + " text not null, " + CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT + " text not null, " + CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT + " integer   );" ;
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_PROJ);     
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ);
        onCreate(db);
    }


}

    public void saveCategoryRecord(Category category) {

         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE , category.getTitle());
         values.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, category.getContent()); 
         values.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT, category.getCount());   
         // Inserting Row
         mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ, null, values);
         mDb.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllProjects() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ, new String[] {CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID, CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE, CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public GinfyDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;

    }

     public GinfyDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
            mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
            mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }


}
```

this is my MainActivity.java
here only i mention my url of json also

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item); 

        mDbHelper=new GinfyDbAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        mDbHelper.open();
         Cursor projectsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllProjects();
         if(projectsCursor!=null)
           {
           fillData(projectsCursor);
           Log.i("filling", "...");
           }
           else
           {
                new GetDataAsyncTask().execute();
           }


        //lv1 =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);   
        //lv =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);



        btnGetSelected = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnget);
        btnGetSelected.setOnClickListener(this);

        myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);



        //praycount.setOnClickListener(this);
        //initView();
    }



    /*private void initView(){
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
        String url = "http://www.ginfy.com/api/v1/posts.json";
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);


    }   */



    private class GetDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("Loading.....");
            Dialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Dialog.dismiss();
            Cursor projectsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllProjects();
            if(projectsCursor!=null)
            {
            mDbHelper=new GinfyDbAdapter(MainActivity.this);
            mDbHelper.open();
            fillData(projectsCursor);
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            getData();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void getData() {
          try
          {
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
      HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://ancient-caverns-4909.herokuapp.com/api/v1/posts.json");
      // HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/mbbangalore/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc");     

      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
      HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
      String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); // content will be consume only once
       Log.i("................",_response);
      httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(_response);
      JSONArray contacts = jsonObject.getJSONArray("post");//(url);
          for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
              JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
              String id = c.getString("id");
              String title = c.getString("title");
              String  content = c.getString("content");
              String  count = c.getString("count");
              mDbHelper=new GinfyDbAdapter(MainActivity.this);
              mDbHelper.open();
              mDbHelper.saveCategoryRecord(new Category(id,title,content,count));
      }
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
       private void fillData(Cursor projectsCursor) {
           //mDbHelper.open();   

           if(projectsCursor!=null)
           {
           String[] from = new String[]{GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT};
           int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text2, R.id.text1, R.id.count};
            dataAdapter  = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
             this, R.layout.activity_row, 
             projectsCursor, 
             from, 
             to,
             0);
            setListAdapter(dataAdapter);
           }else
           {
               Log.i("...........","null");
           }
       }
```

My Database is not upgrading due to JSON change,it will take only one time of json data only.

Comment: everytime you get the data do you add it to your database? `mDbHelper.saveCategoryRecord(new Category(id,title,content,count))` if you get all data then it should be in db . if its db then you can retrieve it and show. check the db first for the data entries

Comment: @Raghunandan no for first time it shows next time its not upgrading dude,it simply display the same data in listview, if possible check my code i sent mail to you

Comment: you mean to say the data in entered int the data base but the update is not getting displayed?

Comment: dude thats only in first time it shows in listview from next time itself my listview is not changing @Raghunandan,pls check your mail dude

Comment: i mean to say the new entry (updated data) is it present in the database?

Comment: how to see that one dude@Raghunandan,i can see only the data of json in the url of rest client,but in db dont know how to see @rRaghunandan

Comment: you can extract the db from file explorer under your package name and then view it with any db viewer suitable fro your os.

Comment: @Raghunandan check your mail,in file explorer not like that is available

Comment: @Raghunandan are you there

Comment: what's happening now?

Comment: @Raghunandan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570269/how-to-update-the-database-while-changing-in-our-server-side